# Prevent MOSFET input being low when connected to output of powered off device

Tags: arduino, mosfet, 74hc595

I am driving a row of LEDs using an P channel logic level MOSFET (SI2323DS-T1-E3CT-ND) to switch power from a bench power supply. The gate is connected via a current limiting resistor to an output of a 74HC165 8 bit shift register.
The shift register VCC is being powered from an Arduino 5V supply, I have connected the grounds between the Arduino power supply and the bench power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOZh9R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gate of the Si2323DS has a pull up resistor, the intention being to turn off the leds until Q1 pulls it low, everything works as expected until I turn off the power to the Arduino, at which time the MOSFET turns on.
It seems that in the "powered off" state the output from the 74HC595 acts like a low resistance pathway to ground and the pull up resistor is unable to raise the gate to a logic 1?

It's important that the MOSFET is off under normal conditions because if all the rows are enabled by default in the final design, an over current condition will occur.

Given this configuration, is there any way to ensure the MOSFET is turned off when the 74HC595 is powered off?

I thought it might be possible to invert the logic using a transistor such that a logic high form the 74HC595 would be required to turn on the MOSFET, but if the problem can be solved with fewer components that would be optimal.

I am only using 2 power supplies during the prototype phase, ultimately the Arduino and the LEDs will be powered from the same PSU.
Thanks for any help/suggestions you can offer.

I should also point out this was just a bench test for using the MOSFET, ultimately I am going to use current sinking high power shift registers (MIC5821) to sink the columns of my LED matrix similar to this [design.](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/attachments/k8lh-powered-bus-matrix-png.27964/)

Comment: You are totally on the right track. If it is allowable to use low side switching, you could use a power N-channel MOSFET instead of the P-channel you are currently using. Put the N-channel between the low-side of the LED's and GND, and drive the gate of that MOSFET directly from the 595. But inverting will also work. You could just add a single N-channel signal MOSFET to drive the gate of the current P-MOS. That is only one extra part, and it would preserve the single GND arrangement you have now, which may be required, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Oh, wait, your mosfet, the si2323, is a P-channel mosfet. I just noticed that you refer to it as N-channel in the text. But it is P-channel.

Comment: Also, I think your schematic is wrong. The bench supply in your schematic does not share a GND with the arduino or HC595 as you say in your text.

Comment: I corrected the mistakes in my diagram, be gentle this is the first time I have created one :-)

Comment: It looks like the bench supply negative terminal is still not connected to GND.

Comment: When the arduino and LED's are powered from the same supply the whole problem will probably go away. The Arduino inputs are sinking current because the Arduino VCC rails are low. So current flows through the pullup, I guess, through the protection diodes of the arduino inputs to the arduino VCC rail.

Comment: I see your point about the supply, less haste more speed.
Note that the gate of the MOSFET is not connected to the Arduino but to the HC595, so the question is, what happens (electrically) to the output of the HC595 when VCC is not present?

Comment: Right. So just substitute HC595 for arduino. Most likely, a diode from HC595 output to HC595 VCC becomes forward biased and passes current. Depending on how hard you are pulling up the output, the result could be that VCC might rise quite high. It can sometimes even rise high enough for the chip to power on and run, although this is not good for the IC, and should be avoided. If it is just a 10k pullup, the IC will probably not power on. Basically, most IC's cannot have voltage applied to any IO pins when VCC is absent. There are exceptions, but they will be noted in the datasheet prominently.

Comment: The diode is an internal diode that is present on most IC's to protect the input or output pin from over-voltage. When VCC is energized, the diode will not be forward biased unless the IO is driven above VCC. But when VCC is at 0V, the diode can easily be forward biased by just a small voltage.

Comment: I added an NPN transistor to the gate of the MOSFET which acts as a logic inverter and also solves the problem of the LEDs being turned on when the power to the Arduino is disconnected.
It also has the advantage of allowing me to swap out the HC595 for a CD4017 decade counter to form the row select protecting me me from ever turning more than one row on at once and creating an over current situation (quite possible with a shift register).

Comment: In the next iteration I will change everything around and use N channel MOSFETs for the rows as a current sink, and MIC5891YN shift registers as current sources for the columns, removing the need for the transistor and pull up resistors.
Thanks all for your help, and patience :-)

Comment: Write up your solution and notes as an answer to your own question. This is allowed/accepted. It is better for our statistics if we don't have too many unanswered questions. Answered questions help future learners more than unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

Its just as you said, you can use an N fet connected to the diode resistors and to ground, that has 4 advantages:

1: Your problem gets instantly solved, and

2: N channel MOSFETs tend to have lower resistance than a P channel ones of the same size

3: You don't need a pull up resistor which consumes power when the MOSFET is off (not that it is a lot of energy tough).

4: if you decide to use many diodes in series hence increasing the needed led PSU voltage the circuit remains unchanged (unless the Vds of the chosen fet is too low).